# 2006 Mazda 6 engine wiring harness short

Tags: connector, fuse-panel

So the main engine harness that plugges into the engine compartment fuse box the green wire and bigger red with yellow stripe that are closed to the firewall has burned out the plug.[image] the plug is one of three that snap together and become one plug.That plugs into the right side of fuse box. It has the 2.3 L engine with manual trans.Does  anyone know where the darker green wire and bigger gauged red/yellow stripe goes to

Comment: That type of damage is usual;ly caused by a poor or loose connection in the plug.

Comment: Should I replace entire engine wiring harness or just fix the plug?

Comment: If you can get both plug and socket then replace them... if not, and only the loom is available ..

Comment: That plug is one of three that slide together make one big plug . It plugs into engine compartment fuse box. On further inspection I noticed a lot of moisture on the plug. Not sure if that’s the reason it shorted out or not.

Answer (score 0):

Mazda released some information about this issue as being common in this year of Mazda.  My car has the same issue.  There should have been some symptoms noticed within the vehicle such as defroster not working properly or ambient air temperature reading incorrectly or like me a crank no start issue which was linked to the fuel pump relay.  I do believe one of those depending on your cars symptoms will be the answer to the question about the wire color.    Unfortunately for me I took my car to the mazda dealership and they didnt listen to what I already knew and let their master mazda mechanic trouble shoot my car for over a week and charged me $300.00 and didn't fix it.  I have two identical Mazdas that wont start.  Good luck.